# how to compound the interest monthly in recurring deposit calculation?

Tags: math

how to calculate recurring deposit in monthly basis?

```
M = ( R * [(1+r)n - 1 ] ) / (1-(1+r)-1/3) 

M is Maturity value
R is deposit amount
r is rate of interest
n is number of quarters
```

if i take 'n' as 4(no of Quarters) for 1 year its showing yearly Maturity value.can anyone tel me how to do **monthly** calculation.Thanks

Comment: I don't think this question is related to Ruby-on-Rails. is it?

Comment: http://vindeep.com/Calculators/RDCalc.aspx - this site gives correct maturity value for monthly compounding.but i dont know how to give 'n' value

Comment: @Wali Ali: im doing recurring deposit calculation in ruby on rails

Comment: @Akila This still has nothing to do with Ruby-on-Rails. Ruby is the language so if syntax matters you would just use the 'ruby' tag. Rails is a whole different monster. And this is more a math question than anything. Not much of a programming question.

Comment: @Akila this really is a math question. I'll give you the answer here: n is the number of times the interest is compounded per year. Daily: n = 365; monthly: n = 12; quarterly: n = 4; semi-annual: n = 2; annually: n = 1

Comment: @WaliAli: if i take 'n' as 12 im getting wrong output.but http://vindeep.com/Calculators/RDCalc.aspx-this site shows exact vale.anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the 1/3 is doing in the denominator, could you explain that? As integer division it will likely evaluate to 0 anyway.

---

That said, the formula for payment at the end of each payment interval is indeed

> M = R * ( (1+r/p)^n-1 )/( (1+r/p) -1) = R * p/r * ( (1+r/p)^n-1 )

resulting in M = 125365.3694 for the given data;

and for payments at the start of each payment interval (month, quarter, ...)

> M = R * (1+r/p)*( (1+r/p)^n-1 )/( (1+r/p) -1) = R * (p/r+1) * ( (1+r/p)^n-1 )

resulting in M = 126357.8452 for the given data.

Here p is the number of parts of the year that is used, i.e., p=4 for quarterly and p=12 for monthly, n is the number of payments, i.e., the payment schedule lasts n/p years, and then r is the nominal annual interest rate, used in r/p to give the interest rate over each part of the year.

---

Note that the effective interest rate (1+r/p)^p-1 depends on p, for p=1 it is r, for very large p it approaches exp(r)-1.

---

A more realistic result is obtained by taking the number of days in each month into account

```
days:=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
for k in [1..12] do 
    sum:=0; 
    for j in [1..12] do 
        sum+:=1; 
        sum*:=1+days[(j+k-1) mod 12 + 1]*0.095/365; 
    end for; 
    k, sum*10000; 
end for;
```

gives as result the maturity value if started in month[k], with k=1 corresponding to january

```
 1 126402.9195
 2 126324.3970
 3 126343.1642
 4 126329.4573
 5 126348.2653
 6 126334.5983
 7 126353.4478
 8 126372.4494
 9 126358.9711
10 126378.0173
11 126364.5825
12 126383.6740
```

Comment: If you have 36 monthly payments, then the payments are done over 36/12=3 years. With 16 quarterly payments you get 16/4=4 years etc.

Comment: okay.but i didn't get correct maturity value.For example,deposit amount is 10000,rate of interest is 9.5%,deposit period is 1 year then its maturity value should be 126358(monthly calculation)

Comment: In matters of financial computations it is important to give all the details, even if they are the most natural of the choices. This value is the result for a payment plan where the payment happens at the begin of the month, and the maturity value is taken at the end of the twelfth month. I added the modified formula for that case. There the result is indeed, using 0.095 as the nominal interest rate, 126357.84520629494681, if it were the effective interest rate, 126089.393913886691 would be the value at maturity.

Comment: can you pls explain me how you took values? p value as 12(because of monthly),R as 10000(deposit amount), r as 0.095(interest rate), n as 1 (12(monthly payments)/12 = 1). is it correct??

Comment: n=12, number of payments. n/p=1 year.

Comment: In Ruby, `^` isn't exponentiation, `**` is.

Comment: But you understood the intended meaning, and that is all what is important here. Is there a difference between using ** and pow?

Comment: @LutzL: I have applied the values in M = R * ( (1+r/p)^n-1 )/( (1+r/p) -1), where R is 10000, r is 0.095, p as 12, n as 1 & i get maturity value as 1263157.89473 but how did you get 126357.84520629494681? i'm doing Recurring deposit calculator that's why i'm asking again and again.help me

Comment: You should get a six digit answer close to 120000=12*10000, your number has 7 digits before the decimal point. Also, you have to apply the second formula, the first gives results around 125000. And lastly, your deposit calculator might still use another computation method where the real length of the months is taken into account, taking r*d/365 with d the number of days in each month as the interest rate for this month. Then the result also depends on which month you are starting with.

Comment: Hi guys. Did anyone manage to get the desired results with this answer and can conclude that this formula works and is worth the time to try? I am in a tight position and time is not on my side. I would love to know if I should go ahead and implement this in PHP. It has not been marked as the correct answer. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You should always get the details on how the nominal and effective interest rate are related. The last program snippet with high probability reflects how banks compute. However, other simplifications also exist, such as calculating with 12 months a 30 days etc. It would be best if you had a handful of completely computed example scenarios to verify your algorithm against.

Comment: For the computation in the vindeep.com/Calculators/RDCalc.aspx calculator linked in the second question-comment, it is the second formula that reproduces its result as you can verify by magnifying the payment rate input to extremely large powers of 10. The result is always proportional to the rate, if everything else is constant.